# Javascript getElementsByClassName - select all elements

Tags: javascript

I want to hide all the elements with class `asp` but the problem is that following code just hides 1 element but doesn't work for other 1000 rows/elements. How can I hide all elements with the class "asp" ?

```js
function toggleFunction() {
    var hide = document.getElementsByClassName('asp')[0].style.visibility='hidden';
}

toggleFunction()
```

Answer (score 4):

The reason you are only hiding one of the is the `[0]`. You are saying "get the list and then take the first".

Try this:

```
var elements = document.getElementsByClassName('asp');

for (var i=0; i<elements.length; i++) {
    elements[i].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Example of solution:

```js
function toggleFunction() {
  var elems = document.getElementsByClassName( 'asp' );
  for ( var i = 0, l = elems.length; i < l; i++ )
    elems[ i ].style.visibility = 'hidden';
}
```

```html
<button type="button" onclick="toggleFunction()">Hide</button>
<div class="asp">1</div>
<div class="asp">2</div>
<div class="asp">3</div>
<div class="asp">4</div>
<div class="asp">5</div>
<div class="asp">6</div>
<div class="asp">7</div>
<div class="asp">8</div>
<div class="asp">9</div>
```

Comment: But I recommend to you to use jQuery for this.